# hbase-default.xml file seems to be for an older version of HBase (null), this version is

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hbase

when i run a sparkSql job ,it happened to me ,but when i do it later,it works ,i have no idea about it because it happened again.if you have any idea , please help me ~~

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:96)
    at com.joinf.hbase.exportData.toMySQL.SparkOnSQLReplaceToHbase$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkOnSQLReplaceToHbase.scala:98)
    at com.joinf.hbase.exportData.toMySQL.SparkOnSQLReplaceToHbase$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkOnSQLReplaceToHbase.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2118)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2118)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , when I increase the memory of driver , it can work fluently .I think it maybe concerned with  memory.